# how the step size be varied in case of steepest ascent method

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I have a doubt regarding steepest ascent method. 
I need to find the **maximum value** of $s$, where $s=x+\frac1y$.   $x$ and $y$ are the parameters that are calculated at different values of $d$ and $d$ varies from $1$ to $10$ with step size of $.015$.
If I directly apply the loop in MathLab to find values of $x$ and $y$ and further $s$ for all values of $d$, the process is lengthy and time consuming.
I am trying to apply **steepest ascent method** with which the step size can be increased/decreased according to the output . can anyone suggest whether this will solve my problem...
secondly, how the step size can be varied...
i.e. if for $d=1$, $x$, $y$ ,hence $s$ is calculated , 
then again calculated $x$,$y$ for $d=1.15$ ($d$+step size) now what next???? please help

Answer (score 1):

In your example,

$$grad(s) = \left(\frac{1}{y}; - \frac{x}{y^2}\right)$$

The steepest ascent method provides an expression how to proceed from an estimate $(x_n;y_n)$ to the improved estimate $(x_{n+1};y_{n+1})$:

$$(x_{n+1};y_{n+1}) = (x_n;y_n) + t * grad(x_n;y_n)$$

The parameter $t$ has to be chosen such that function value $s$ is maximized. Rather than using a fixed step-size, a line-search is performed to optimize the step-size.

In your example:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{t}{y_n}$$
$$y_{n+1} = y_n - \frac{t x_n}{y_n^2}$$
$$s(t) = \left(x_n + \frac{t}{y_n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y_n - \frac{t x_n}{y_n^2}}\right)$$

$$s(t) = \frac{x_n y_n ^3 - x_n t + t y_n^3 - t^2 + y_n^2}{y_n^3 - t}$$

The expression for $s(t)$ is probably best maximized by a numerical method like [golden-section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search).